# Cut mesh into two objects along selected edge

Tags: mesh

I want to cut the mesh along the blue line,I've tried different ways, with no luck

[image]

If I select the 4 edges then press P, then I get a Square shape rather than a mesh, I saw tutorial says edge split in Edge Menu can do the job, but I'm using blender 2.9 there is no such item in the Edge Menu, I dont want to use a plane cut either cause the mesh I'm cutting is a rare case that the edges forms a plane, I want a more universal way of doing this in case of the edges does not falls into a plane.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No worries, the split option is still there :)

1. Select your edge
2. Go *Mesh > Split > Faces By Edges*
3. Done.

[image]